# SVG <text> + Javascript : only first <text> element loads in page

Tags: javascript, svg, responsive-design, appendchild, createelement

In order to make my website headers scalable & centered SVGs, I used the following HTML & Javascript (along with some custom CSS):

HTML:

```
<h1 id="page-title"><span id="fallback-title">Scalable Title</span>
<svg viewbox="0 0 1200 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" id="svg-title"></svg>
</h1>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
(function() {
var fallback_title, page_title, supportsSVG, svgDoc, textNode, title, title_text;

supportsSVG = function() {
return !!document.createElementNS && !!document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
"svg").createSVGRect;
};

if (supportsSVG) {
fallback_title = document.querySelector("#fallback-title");
fallback_title.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
title_text = fallback_title.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
page_title = document.querySelector("#page-title");
svgDoc = document.querySelector("#svg-title");
title = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "text");
title.setAttributeNS(null, "x", '50%');
title.setAttributeNS(null, "y", '50%');
title.setAttributeNS(null, "text-anchor", 'middle');
textNode = document.createTextNode(title_text);
svgDoc.appendChild(title);
title.appendChild(textNode);
}

}).call(this);
```

I can see that the first header in the page is displaying as SVG, while the following headers display as my fallbacks. I suspect this has to do with the 'appendChild' portion of my JS.

Is there any odd reason why the script would be loading only to the first header of the page and not the ones following? Such as the order in which the script is loading in relation to other scripts or even the action of the page loading.

Has anyone ever experienced something similar? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean "only the first". I see only one element. Does your actual page have more than one element with the same id? If so that's invalid, you should use classes instead.

Comment: Also. "viewbox" should be "viewBox".

Comment: Thanks Robert and Paul for the quick reply. And yes Robert, I basically reproduced the same code for all the h1s in my page - I realize IDs shouldn't be used for more than one element, so if I change it to classes and alter `page_title = document.querySelector("#page-title");` to something like `page_title = document.querySelector(".page-title");` should that resolve the issue?

Comment: Also I should mention I have inserted the above JS into my theme's 'Custom JS' box, which means (I assume) that the code is the last to load in the html sheet/page.

Comment: this is the Codepen I followed, but even if you duplicate h1's in this example you will see that only the first element generates as SVG: http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/nheBL